kivy output to label or button or screen
What I need to do is output to maybe a label below the submit button right now it prints to console can anyone tell me the code to do this?
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 1

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Sale Price: ", font_size=100))
        self.name = TextInput(input_filter="int", multiline=False, font_size=150)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.name)


        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text="Run the Numbers", font_size=100)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        name = int(self.name.text)
        calc = name * .0975
        tax = name + calc
        #######first franklin#########
        #######6 months#######
        a = tax * .06
        b = tax + a
        c = b / 6
        ######12 months#####
        d = tax * .08
        e = tax + d
        f = e / 12
        ######24 months####
        g = tax * .15
        h = tax + g
        i = h / 24
        ########Synchrony########

        #####24 months 0#####
        j = tax * .14
        k = tax + j
        l = k / 24

        #####36 months 0#####
        m = tax * .18
        n = tax + m
        o = n / 36

        ##### 24 months 0 #####
        p = tax * .14
        q = tax + p
        r = q / 48

        ##### 6 months deferred #####
        p = tax * .14
        q = tax + p
        r = q / 48

        print("First Franklin Loans")
        print(c, "for 6 months total cost:", b)
        print(f, "for 12 months total cost:", e)
        print(i, "for 24 months total cost:", h)
        print(" ")
        print("Synchrony Loans")
        print("Deferred Interest Loans")
        print("Deferred for 6 months total cost")
        print("Deferred for 12 months total cost")
        print("Deferred for 18 months total cost")
        print("No Interest loans")
        print(l, "for 24 months total cost:", k)
        print(o, "for 36 months total cost:", n)
        print(r, "for 48 months total cost:", q)

        self.name.text = ""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()

just either print to label below or a pop up window with new data in it. Wouldn't let me post unless I added more to it. There is nothing else I can think to ask so please ignore this section of the post its only so I can get it to post

In you __init__() method, you can add a `Label' for your result:
    self.result = Label(text='Result')
    self.inside.add_widget(self.result)

Then set the text of that Label in the pressed() method to whatever your result is:
    self.result.text = "for 48 months total cost: " + str(q)


I was hoping to just output all calculations in one label like have the label call for the results from def pressed would it be possible to do something like self.result.text = " for 48 months total cost:" + str(q) "\n" for 36 months....... and repeat?

Yes, but you would either have to build one string that has all the results, and assign that string to the Label text. Or repeat the line in my answer for each result using += instead of = for the second line and onward.

ok thank you I will build the string to store it and then call with your method thank you

sorry 1 last question how can I change height of the results box? right now it cuts everything off its running as 1 long string across

You need to add '\n' characters to separate the lines. You should have a look at this documentation and this.
